# How to iterate through variable of variable provided in array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var data1: [{
    {
        postalcode:'qwerty',
        cT: 23,
        latitude:57.232324,
        longitude: -2.343543,
        call_reason: 'xyz',
        Call_Sub_reason:'abc'
    },
    {
        postalcode:'qwerty1',
        cT: 43,
        latitude:57.223524,
        longitude: -1.435453,
        call_reason: 'xyz1',
        Call_Sub_reason:'abc1'
    },
    .
    .
    .
    {
    .
    .
    }
}];
```

---

want data in this format:

```
var data1 : [{
    {
        postalcode:'qwerty',
        cT: 23,
        location:[57.232324,-2.343543],
        call_reason: 'xyz',
        Call_Sub_reason:'abc'
    },

    {
        postalcode:'qwerty1',
        cT: 65,
        location:[58.232324,-1.343543],
        call_reason: 'xyz1',
        Call_Sub_reason:'abc1'
    },

    {
    .
    .
    }
}];
```

Comment: That's not a valid syntax.

Comment: If my data is in this format in database and I want data in the following mentioned type .. how can I get it?

Comment: The data format you provided is not correct, and wait a minute, are both format same ? I mean, you provided one format and expected it in the same format ?

Comment: As above: `[{{` is how your JSON starts, that is invalid syntax. Also, keys should be quoted and double quotes should be used, not single quotes.

Comment: @Towkir A new key is used, which is a concatenation of longitude and latitude.

Comment: What do you mean by `var data` **:** `[{...}]`? why is there a colon? and what is the point of having an array which contains objects of objects?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following (given you fix the syntax issue in your JSON response):

```
var formatted = data1.map(x => {
    var xy = Object.assign({}, x);

    xy.location = [xy.latitude, xy.longitude]
    delete xy.latitude;
    delete xy.longitude;

    return xy;
});
```

```js
var items = [{ postalcode:'qwerty', cT: 23, latitude:57.232324, longitude: -2.343543, call_reason: 'xyz', Call_Sub_reason:'abc' }, { postalcode:'qwerty1', cT: 43, latitude:57.223524, longitude: -1.435453, call_reason: 'xyz1', Call_Sub_reason:'abc1' }];

var formatted = items.map(x => {
  var xy = Object.assign({}, x);
  
  xy.location = [xy.latitude, xy.longitude]
  delete xy.latitude;
  delete xy.longitude;
  
  return xy;
})

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: Well, you beat me by 3 minutes so have in upvote in lieu of me deleting my _identical_ answer. I was too busy getting distracted lol

Comment: Be arware, that "items.map" will change the "items" array as well and not only the new "formattedItems" array.

Comment: @DanielFrech Good spot. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "iterate through variable of variable in array" ?

Both of the data you wrote are the same, if you meant that you would like to loop through the items in the array, you can do so like this:

es5

```
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  var dataItem = data1[i];
  /**
   * dataItem will be
   * { postalcode:'qwerty', cT: 23, location:[57.232324,-2.343543], call_reason: 'xyz', Call_Sub_reason:'abc' },
   */
}
```

es6

```
for (let dataItem of data1) {
  // same
}
```

Comment: They're not the same... A new key is added called `location` which combines latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

```js
var arr = [{
        postalcode:'qwerty',
        cT: 23,
        latitude:57.232324,
        longitude: -2.343543,
        call_reason: 'xyz',
        Call_Sub_reason:'abc'
    },
    {
        postalcode:'qwerty1',
        cT: 43,
        latitude:57.223524,
        longitude: -1.435453,
        call_reason: 'xyz1',
        Call_Sub_reason:'abc1'
    }];
    
   var result =  arr.map(
   ({postalcode, cT, latitude, longitude, call_reason, Call_Sub_reason}) => ({postalcode, location: [ latitude, longitude], cT, call_reason, Call_Sub_reason})
   );
   console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array `map` which will create a new array and return the object

```js
var data1 = [{
    postalcode: 'qwerty',
    cT: 23,
    latitude: 57.232324,
    longitude: -2.343543,
    call_reason: 'xyz',
    Call_Sub_reason: 'abc'
  },
  {
    postalcode: 'qwerty1',
    cT: 43,
    latitude: 57.223524,
    longitude: -1.435453,
    call_reason: 'xyz1',
    Call_Sub_reason: 'abc1'

  }
];


let newArray = data1.map((item) => {
  return {
    postalcode: item.postalcode,
    cT: item.cT,
    location: item.location,
    call_reason: item.call_reason,
    Call_Sub_reason: item.Call_Sub_reason
  }
})
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of @Adriani6, the following does the same but leaves the data1 array unchanged if that is needed to avoid possible side effects:

```js
const items = [{ postalcode:'qwerty', cT: 23, latitude:57.232324, longitude: -2.343543, call_reason: 'xyz', Call_Sub_reason:'abc' }, { postalcode:'qwerty1', cT: 43, latitude:57.223524, longitude: -1.435453, call_reason: 'xyz1', Call_Sub_reason:'abc1' }];

let formattedItems = items.map(item => {
  let newItem = {...item};
  newItem.location = [newItem.latitude, newItem.longitude];
  delete newItem.latitude;
  delete newItem.longitude;
  return newItem;
});

console.log(items);
console.log(formattedItems);
```